# Rename files using SFTP

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp

there is a project assigned to me that create some files and send those files using SFTP to some server. there is another programme to read and send that files to another place(the files first programme sent to the server). it checks continuously new files from the server and read it and send. but the problem is sometimes the second program read files not completely imported to that server. that cause system to crash. they told me to do change in the first program before sending files, rename the files first and send and after finished upload rename again the sent files, files that in the server. is this possible to or is a there better way to do this. is there anyone have some ideas I'm kindly asking to share with me

Comment: So what is your question? How to *"Rename files using SFTP"*, as per the title? For that we need to know what SFTP library are you using - Or *"is this possible to or is a there better way to do this"*? - Also FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols, so make sure you know which one are you using, and use one of the tags only.

Comment: the first program I mentioned is kind an old program. it is from time to time upgraded to FTP to FTPS and to SFTP. what i asked is is it possible to rename uploaded files. and the better way i asked is 'is there a way upload files without rename and without getting the system to crash'(to stop picking files that not uploaded correctly ). also I'm not sure i mentioned about FTP .sry for my bad english sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That it's a good synchronization method, I mean using a temporary name during the transfer and the rename at once at the end.

The implementation depends on which approach you've used in the program.
It should be something like this:

```
    //  Rename the file or directory:
    success = sftp.RenameFileOrDir("oldFilename.txt","newFilename.txt");
    if (success != true) {
        Console.WriteLine(sftp.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }
```

Basically:

1. Catch the event of transfer completed
2. Request the RENAME command